# Codecademy Ruby course: Control Flow know-how

Tags: ruby

When coding in Ruby, I came up with an error about needing to state all words the user inputed. I tried to change my code to get it to output that, but the problem remained. Here is my code and the Ruby instructions.

Instructions
Add an if/else statement inside your .each.

if the current word equals the word to be redacted, then print "REDACTED " with that extra space.
Otherwise (else), print word + " ".
The extra space in both cases prevents the words from running together.

```
    puts text = gets.chomp
    puts redact = gets.chomp
    words = text.split(" ")
    words = ['hi', 'hello', 'what', 'why']
    words.each do |word|
       if gets = words
          print "Redact "
     else

          print word + "Incorrect"
     end
   end
```

The problem it says I have with my code is... Oops, try again. Make sure to print each word from the user's text to the console unless that word is the word to be redacted; if it is, print REDACTED (all caps!).

I would appreciate all help, please and thank you.

Comment: you might want to repeat several previous lessons/challenges, to refresh your memory/knowledge.

Comment: Bruteforcing code into submission (without understanding it) is not very productive :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest editing your post: remove the story about codecademy submission; only tell how your output is different from what you expected. People here will be more likely to help you.

Comment: Have you tried running the code yourself? Can describe what you expected it to do, and what is it actually doing? (as @MarioTrucco suggests)

Comment: Yes I have tried on codecademy and what happens is that if I don't put a word in "words" it prints REDAT REDAT REDAT REDAT and then what is contained in the "words" variable. I believe what it should do is if the user input doesn't match a word in the variable "words" it should print what is in the "words" and incorrect. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Ben sorry these guys aren't being too helpful. :D It's been awhile but I hope this helps. In the first section titled "What you'll be building" Codecademy gives you the exact example (the answer) to the final problem in the section. This is always true and may help in the future. What you're looking for:

```
puts "Text to search through: "
text = gets.chomp
puts "Word to redact: "
redact = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |word|
    if word != redact
        print word + " "
    else
    print "REDACTED "
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have pass several years I know, but I wanted pass and let my solution for this excercise.

```ruby
puts "Text to search through: "
text = gets.chomp
puts "Word to redact: "
redact = gets.chomp

words = text.split(',')  # "," is necessary to identify each of the words
words.each do |x|
  if x == redact  # if words repeat, print REDACTED
    print "REDACTED"
  else  # else, only write de word and space
    print x + " "
  end
end
```